# Float li - одинаковый вертикальный отступ вместо наибольшего

Tags: html, css, float, ul

Есть `ul` с такими стилями:

```
.li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.li:first {
  clear: both;
}
```

Проблема в том, что если какой-то из li занимает больше места по вертикали, чем другие в строке, то отступ для менее высоких будет равен 10px + разница их высоты с самым 'высоким'.

[image: Сейчас]

А что хотелось бы видеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте сам ul в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае нужно использовать библиотеку [Masonry](http://wp-kama.ru/id_2818/masonry-vyivod-html-blokov-v-vide-kirpichnoy-kladki.html)

Comment: А можно без библиотек? Сайт и так тяжелый.

Comment: Нет. CSS это не решает.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю подойдёт ли, но это можно точно решить с помощью flexbox *(вот [здесь](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/) хорошая статья, возможно старовата)*

Единственное: с поддержкой браузерами не всё гладко - только современные, а IE 11 вообще частично :(